# About Byte.valueOf((byte)0xff) exception in android

Tags: java, android

I'm a Android developer,and there is a piece of code.

```
ArrayList<Byte> list = new ArrayList<>();
byte a = (byte) 0xff;
list.add(a);
```

this piece of code is ok in unit test and most mobile phone.but i found some crash event log in some phones data collect.

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=256; index=383
at java.lang.Byte.valueOf(Byte.java:300)
```

I can find this code from Byte.java near at line 300

```
public static Byte valueOf(byte b) {
    return VALUES[b + 128];
}
```

I don't know why. can parameter byte b>128 ? and how to fix them?

Comment: a byte cannot be >= 128.  This looks like `b` is not actually a byte.

Comment: I tested this and it gave me no trouble.  What version of Java are you using?

Comment: If `b` is a byte, it cannot be *less* than -128, so adding 128 is guaranteed to produce a non-negative result: that is to say, a valid array index. It also can't be > 127, that is to say it can't have the value `383`, or `383-128`. *Ergo* (i) it wasn't produced by the value `(byte)0xff`, and (ii) it wasn't produced by the `Byte.valueOf()` code you posted.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if this is some phone manufacturer's fault...

Comment: I found this crash only occurs on some specific models that 。so maybe i have to brow that phone to test.